# Bounds on probability with absolute value

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've stumbled upon this in a larger proof:

> We require
> $$
> \Pr \left(|x| \geq \frac{\sigma^2 \varepsilon}{\Delta f} - \frac{\Delta f}{2} \right) < \delta,
> $$
> and because we are concerned with $|x|$ we will find $\sigma$ such that
> $$
> \Pr \left(x \geq \frac{\sigma^2 \varepsilon}{\Delta f} - \frac{\Delta f}{2} \right) < \frac{\delta}{2}.
> $$

From the context, $\varepsilon \geq 0$,  $\Delta f \geq 0$,  $\delta \geq 0$ are all constants ( $\in \mathbb{R}$).

$x$ is distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ but I don't know if that matters.

Can someone enlighten me? Intuitively it feels that without the absolute value, the probability $\delta$ is split into two halves, but how can I prove it? Is it something specific to $\mathcal{N}$ or does it hold in general?

Comment: This follow from the symmetry of a normal distribution. However, you have to be sure that $\frac{\sigma ^2 \varepsilon }{\Delta f}-\frac{\Delta f}{2}>0$. If $\varepsilon $ is too small, this condition won't hold...

Comment: In general if $X$ has a distribution symmetric w.r.t. $0$ and $c>0$ then: $$P(|X|\geq c)=P(X\geq c)+P(X\leq -c)=P(X\geq c)+P(-X\geq c)=2P(X\geq c)$$This because $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I think that's exactly the point, many thanks. So the last step is that for any symmetric distribution w.r.t. 0 (which Gaussian is), we have $\Pr(-X \geq c) = \Pr(X \geq c)$ which completes the proof.